# Ignoring argument

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

So I'm trying to test a method `methodUnderTest` which is something like this:

```
methodUnderTest{
    //Other stuff that works nice
    this.setterMethod(OtherClass.methodThatErrors(arg1));
}
```

So I'm trying to avoid that static method call `methodThatErrors`.

What I'm doing so far:

```
ClassUnderTest spy = Mockito.spy(objectOfClassUnderTest);
Mockito.doNothing().when(spy).setterMethod(Mockito.any(OtherClass.class));
```

However this does not work, the method is still being called. I would've thought that it shouldn't call the argument method at all because I've written `any` for the argument of `setterMethod`. So how can I prevent this call using Mockito, not PowerMockito.

Edit:

So I managed to mock it by moving the static method call like so:

```
methodUnderTest{
    this.extraSetterMethod(arg1);
}

extraSetterMethod(arg1){
    this.setterMethod(OtherClass.methodThatErrors(arg1));
}
```

I don't really like this solution because it's adding several extra lines of code (even more with javadoc) which just makes the class messier.

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't want to take the opposite approach and return a mock from the static class as opposed to mocking the behavior with the setter?

Comment: @Makoto I thought you couldn't mock static classes with mockito?

Comment: If you use PowerMockito, you can.  My question was why were you taking that option off the table.

Comment: @Makoto oh right, yeh we don't use PowerMockito here as a policy for a number of reasons, namely due to performance issues, as with thousands of tests, using powerMockito would take a much longer time.

Comment: Is methodThatErrors() a static method of OtherClass?  If not you could mock the OtherClass instead of the ClassUnderTest.

Comment: @CarlManaster yes it's static,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the value is coming *directly* from the static method, and not the setter itself.  Whatever value it's getting is coming from the real invocation of the method itself.  Mocking out the call to the setter has no effect; it's not the result of the setter that's in error.

This is a scenario in which you have to make a hard decision:

- Introduce a parameter to the method so that the call can be easier to mock, or
- Use PowerMockito to mock out the call.

I ***strongly*** encourage the latter, especially if you're dealing with a legacy code base which is not very forgiving to a signature change.

Comment: can you explain why you don't recommend the former? Also I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that, is it like the solution I pointed out in my edit using another method?

Comment: A legacy code base which is a bit of a tangled mess; there aren't that many tests for it and/or the usage has been prescribed by some rigid approval process which is inflexible to change.  The bigger issue is that your company prohibits the use of a library that can make testing the kind of code they write *easier*, which is mind boggling.

Comment: What if it's not legacy code? I can see the point though, the idea for these tests is to be run every time someone merges changes to make sure they haven't broken anything, PowerMockito causes the tests to take far longer, which would result in a lot of wasted time and even people who would not run the tests. It's not that it's prohibited, it's just strongly discouraged, (re)writing code to be testable is often a better solution

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you believe them to take far longer.  Perhaps there are other parts of this test suite that are causing it to slow down; in my experience, PowerMockito has added very little overhead overall.  While rewriting the code to make it testable is a good goal, one motivation behind using the mock is to make testable even if you can't rewrite it.